# Error UnknownAsset when trying to increase AssetBalance

Tags: balances, assets, token

The error is shown in substrate-frontend

```
Transaction Failed! system.ExtrinsicFailed::{"token":"UnknownAsset"}
```

`Score` is an asset in pallet_template,
in `build` function of `BuildGenesisConfig`, I initialize the asset with id 1 for all acccounts.

```
<T as pallet::Config>::Score::create(1u32.into(), account.clone(), true, min_balance);
```

The line causes that error as bellow

```
pub fn deposit_score(origin: OriginFor<T>, amt: BalanceOf<T>)-> DispatchResult {
   let score = T::do_convert_tokens_to_credits(&sender, amt);
   T::Score::mint_into(1u32.into(), &sender, score.clone())?;
...
}
```

I want to increase by an amount `score` for the balance of asset `Score` with id `1`
So, How to fix that error? and manage to increase?